# aparece barra de desplazamiento al colocar footer en pagina

Tags: html, css

Tengo un problema con un footer CSS ya que no se ajusta a la ventana del navegador y aparece la barra de desplazamiento cuando se cambia el tamaño de la ventana, alguien me puede ayudar

```
    .footer {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
    width:100%;}

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container text-right">
        <span class="text-right" style="font-size:10px">
            <img src="~/img/logo.png" width="30" height="30" /> &copy;@@DateTime.Now.Year
        </span>
    </div>
</footer>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Quita a su contenedor padre, que en este caso es la etiqueta `body` el `margin` que tiene por defecto de este modo:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

**Explicación**

- Recuerda que los navegadores por *defecto* colocan algunos estilos a las etiquetas
- El `margin` es el margen que tu `footer` tiene en relación con la etiqueta superior que lo contiene, el `body` para este escenario
- Al aplicar `margin: 0;` le estamos indicando que deje sin medidas a los cuatro lados, que sería superior, inferior, izquierdo y derecho; lo cual es lo mismo que las propiedades:

  - `margin-bottom`
  - `margin-top`
  - `margin-left`
  - `margin-right`

Answer (score 0):

Basta con que le des al footer una posición en el eje horizontal ya que se la has dado en el vertical y estás en "position: absolute":

```
.footer {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:100%;
}
```

puede ser left o right, es indiferente:

```
.footer {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: lo coloque como lo indicas pero al momento de reducir el tamañp del navegador al tamaño de la imagen que muestro arriba me coloca el footer a mitad de pagina y no al final de la pagina

Comment: eso simplemente no es posible con el código que facilitas. Si hay más código css que influya sobre el footer es otro caso, pero la clase "footer" que se aplica sobre el contendor no puede color la imagen a un lado u otro. además tienes forzado el tamaño de la imagen a 30x30 px, no sé en que supuesto querrías reducir el navegador a ese tamaño.

Comment: es que estoy haciendolo responsivo es por eso que cambio el tamaño del navegador

Comment: no hay ningun dispositivo ni resolución de pantalla de 30x30px. He probado el código que facilitas con la respuesta que he dado y no responde como comentas. En caulquier caso no pasa nada, espero que hayas podido solucionarlo y el site/app quede bien. Un saludo